# What is the soundtrack that plays when Neo is kissing Trinity in The Matrix Reloaded?

Tags: the-matrix, music-identification

What is the soundtrack that plays when Neo is kissing Trinity in *The Matrix Reloaded*?
It has loud organ music in the background.

Comment: [Fighting the urge to suggest a certain internet meme]

Comment: @Ben : Don't hold back !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is part of the *Matrix Reloaded Suite* by Don Davis. I'm no music expert so comparing the notes was a bit awkward but I think it is around the 15 minutes 20 seconds mark in the song.